# Symfony2 FormBuilder form tag isn't using all forms

Tags: html, forms, symfony, twig

I got a form in formbuilder

**ColleagueType**

```
     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('firstname', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Voornaam'
        ))
        ->add('lastname', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Achternaam'
        ))
        ->add('email', 'email', array(
            'label' => 'Email'
        ))
        ->add('phonenumber', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Telefoon Nummer'
        ))
        ->add('saveNewColleague', 'submit');
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'colleague';
}
```

I used the forms in my twig template like this:

**newcolleague.html.twig**

```
    <div class="container-fluid container-homepage">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            {{ form_start(colleagueform) }}
                {{ form_widget(colleagueform.firstname) }}
                {{ form_widget(colleagueform.lastname) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                {{ form_widget(colleagueform.email) }}
                {{ form_widget(colleagueform.phonenumber) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
                {{ form_widget(colleagueform.saveNewColleague) }}
            {{ form_end(colleagueform) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the formbuilder uses only the `<form>` tag for the first 2 forms

**Rendered Form**

```
    <div class="container-fluid container-homepage">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <form name="colleague" method="post" action="">
                            <input id="colleague_firstname" name="colleague[firstname]" required="required" class="form-control" type="text">
                            <input id="colleague_lastname" name="colleague[lastname]" required="required" class="form-control" type="text">
        </form></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input id="colleague_email" name="colleague[email]" required="required" class="form-control" type="email">
                            <input id="colleague_phonenumber" name="colleague[phonenumber]" required="required" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
                <button type="submit" id="colleague_saveNewColleague" name="colleague[saveNewColleague]" class="btn">Save new colleague</button>
                        <input id="colleague__token" name="colleague[_token]" class="form-control" value="od_0C8daL7V4G0QQFikLHZUBNtE86TSAUIEqbjH9eHk" type="hidden">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template doesn't have correct HTML structure. The form start tag is not in the same div as the form end tag. Correct template would look like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid container-homepage">
    {{ form_start(colleagueform) }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            {{ form_widget(colleagueform.firstname) }}
            {{ form_widget(colleagueform.lastname) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            {{ form_widget(colleagueform.email) }}
            {{ form_widget(colleagueform.phonenumber) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            {{ form_widget(colleagueform.saveNewColleague) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ form_end(colleagueform) }}
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. if you're satsfied with the answer, please mark it as accepted - it helps us to identify question, that still need attention easier. Thx.

Comment: In about 1 or 2 minutes I can click on it, will do :)